# #text won't disapear, even with complex CSS selectors

Tags: css, text

I searched a lot here and I do not think there is already an answer.

**Only in CSS :**
I want the first `woocommerce-Price-amount` span to be the only one displayed. I can `display: none` the second but the `–` which is considered as "#text" by the console won't disapear.

So I have something like :

```
ARTICLE
160.00€ –
```

The – is making me crazy...

```
<span class="price">
    <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
        160.00
        <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">
            €
        </span>
    </span>
 – 
    <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
        1 260.00
        <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">
            €
        </span>
    </span>
</span>
```

Every changes I made sure that nothing overwrite my CSS lines.
I tried `text-indent: -999px`, `color: transparent` the parent and `color: black` the child, and more but nothing works...

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply set the `font-size` of the `.price` span to 0, and then override this in the `amount` span, as shown in this snippet below:

```css
span.price {
  font-size: 0;
}

span.woocommerce-Price-amount.amount {
  font-size: initial;
}

span.woocommerce-Price-amount.amount:nth-of-type(2) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<span class="price">
    <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
        160.00
        <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">
            €
        </span>
    </span>
 – 
    <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
        1 260.00
        <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">
            €
        </span>
    </span>
</span>
```

Of course, this doesn't remove the dash it just, effectively, hides it.